# Google Map show grey if don't have map.fitBounds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my live demo http://plnkr.co/edit/04jDAwoSQbIGhNUlO5n0?p=preview , try to click the button first and see if you can see the working map or just a grey area like me. Then uncomment the last line, in my test it work.
I have search for this "grey issue" but it seem each link show different isuue.
I'm using Google Chrome 33 on Linux 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've ommitted the **required** map-options `zoom` and `center`